# Mix up of two domains in Google search

Tags: dns, google-search, google-search-console

I would like to know why my two apps hosted on different server get mixed up in the search result in Google.

I have [vym.io](https://vym.io) and [remotebase.io](https://remotebase.io). When I google 'site:vym.io', I get all the pages that belong to remotebase.io. When I click the results, I am directed to vym.io, and there is nothing on that route.

[image]

When I google 'remotebase.io', the result has title for vym.io but has a link to remotebase.io. But when I google 'site:remotebase.io', I get the correct result.

[image]
[image]

I spent hours trying to debug why the results are mixed up. Any help?

**More info**

- I compared `<meta name="google-site-verification" ...>` tag for both websites, and they are using different keys.
- The websites are associated with different properties on google analytics.
- The apps are hosted on different server with different IP.

Comment: Looks like the problem is solved. How did you do it? Answer your own question.

Answer (score 0):

After checking your HTML source, you don't have  tag in the  and you are filing the title using JS.

Try to disable the JS from your browsers using "Web developer Tool" and you will see that you will get a white page and the page title in the browser is empty (you will get your URL)

To solve this problem, simple add  tag in the  with your website name and slogan (its up to you to choose the title) and remove the JS code that fills it.

And for your question why you get the page title from your other website, maybe you have backlinks from the other domain pointing to this one.

No need to do anything regarding the backlinks, only make the above change and you will see the magic.

Also don't forget to make redirection from the non-WWW version to WWW version using 301 redirect, this will avoid content duplication and will boost your rank.

Also add your website to Google webmaster as two properties to check the health of your websites.

Comment: Simply adding <meta> won't fix the problem described in the first screenshot. It seems to be a DNS issue: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/webmasters/SSLJ974Rl0s;context-place=forum/webmasters Any other ideas?